# Generate GCC options from #include on Linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc, header

I'd like to build a tool for students that would recommend which GCC options to use by inspecting the `#include` they've used. For instance:

```
#include <math.h>      // recommend -lm
#include <zlib.h>      // recommend -lz
#include <pthread.h>   // recommend -pthread
```

Is there somewhere a list of such associations for standard and classical libraries?
I just need it for GCC and Linux.

-- EDIT

As it looks like that there is no known solution, I've started to build such a list, together with a simple wrapper script inspired from `pkg-config`: [see GitHub repo](https://github.com/fpom/had)

Comment: It gets tricky when you start using things like X11 (behind GUI applications).  Also, you may need a `-L /where/it/is` option too, which can change.  The `pkg-config` system can help sometimes.

Comment: This is a great question, but I doubt there is a systematic way to do it. Having said that, I suspect it wouldn't be hard to maintain a list of mappings manually, for the libraries that student assignments are likely to use.

Comment: I'm currently searching for such a manually maintained list indeed. I agree it's probably not difficult to maintain it, but I wouldn't like to start from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `-M` option of GCC to list all the header files which will be used for the compilation.
After that you should be able to create a script which matches the output with the headers you want to mark.

-- EDIT

Here is a possible script for this ; I don't think it's the most relevant or the best way to do it, but it works pretty well for this usage:

```
FILES="main.c" # For example

OUTPUT=$(gcc -M $FILES)

for LINE in ${OUTPUT[@]}
do
    case $(echo $LINE | rev | cut -d"/" -f1 | rev) in
        "math.h")
            echo "You should use -lm"
            ;;
        "pthread.h")
            echo "You should use -pthread"
            ;;
        "zlib.h")
            echo "You should use -lz"
            ;;
        # And so on with all the files you want to tag
    esac
done
```

Comment: Indeed, this yields the list of `.h` files used in the program. But then, I need to know for each one which library it corresponds to, if any (eg, to add `-lm` or `-lz`), and which option it requires (eg to add `-pthread`). And this is exactly the information I lack.

Comment: Indeed, collecting up the list of headers is the easy part of the job.

Comment: @FranckPommereau I don't think this is possible with GCC directly, that's why I said that it should be possible with a script that parses the output of the command (I edited my post to show what I had in mind for the script)

Comment: @SylvainChaugny Indeed, that's what I would do, but the real problem is to get a list of cases as complete as possible.

Comment: @FranckPommereau I don't think this is possible, because as some libraries are not included by default (eg. libm), GCC can't know you will need it as it doesn't need it itself, so I think this is the "best" way to do it